# Possible to create a classmethod as a non-decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, class-method

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, string=''):
        self.string = string
    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, string):
        return cls(string=string)
```

The classmethod in the above case isn't necessary, as I could just as easily call `Item(string='asdf')` instead of `Item.from_string(string='asdf')`, but I'm just using it as an example.

Is it possible to attach an arbitrary [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#classmethod) outside of the class itself? For example, something like:

```
def from_string(cls, string):
    return cls(string=string)

classmethod(from_string(Item, "asdf"))
```

Or, to write it something like this:

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, string=''):
        self.string = string
    from_string = classmethod(f)
    def f(string):
        return Item(string)
```

Basically, I'm trying to understand decorators a bit more and how they might be used outside of their normal context (to see what they do behind the scenes).

Comment: What did you want `classmethod` to do in `classmethod(from_string(Item, "asdf"))`? I don't see what role it would play. If you want to call `from_string`, you don't need to involve `classmethod` at all; `from_string(Item, "asdf")` works fine.

Comment: Just assign your "classmethod(...)" to e. g. "Item.from_string". The actual magic here is the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
@classmethod
def from_string(cls, string):
    return cls(string=string)
```

is equivalent to

```py
def from_string(cls, string):
    return cls(string=string)
from_string = classmethod(from_string)
```

---

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self, string=''):
        self.string = string
    from_string = classmethod(f)
    def f(string):
        return Item(string)
```

should be rearranged to

```py
class Item:
    def __init__(self, string=''):
        self.string = string
    def f(string):
        return Item(string)
    from_string = classmethod(f)
```

Comment: That equivalence doesn't *quite* hold in some contexts (mostly weird metaclasses), since the decorator version only performs one assignment to `from_string`, while the non-decorator version performs two. For most purposes, the versions may be considered equivalent.